# Android Viewpager items gone invisible while the Fragment is started. But reappearing after locking and unlocking device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, notifydatasetchanged

> *[N.B. This problem is from an old app; developed couple of years ago. Back then the app was working fine]*

**Case 1:**
I was trying to show some SQLite data inside a fragment. (Extending `Listfragment` and using `viewPager`).
The problem is the data was showing but not updating while the app was running. I tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
It was not working either. Only When I relaunch the app, the updated data shows up.

**Case 2:**
Then I tried to use `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` while fragment is visible. Now when I navigate to that fragment from any other fragments, the container/viewpager gone *invisible*. But when I lock and unlock my device while staying on that fragment, the data shows up. **But still data is not updated**

Either way, I can not view updated data without relaunching app.

I am attaching the code which I tried,

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ScannerFragmentList.OnScannerListFragmentInteractionListener {
    
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ProgressDialog barcodeDownloadingProgressDialog;
    private int[] tabIcons = { R.drawable.ic_camera, R.drawable.ic_history };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpToolBar();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

   
    if (PreferenceUtil.isStartInScanModeOn(getApplicationContext())){
        onListFragmentInteraction(null,-1,0);
    }
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new ScannerFragmentList(), getString(R.string.scan));
    adapter.addFrag(new HistoryFragment(), getString(R.string.history));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + " " + position);
        if (position == 0) {
            return ScannerFragmentList.newInstance(1);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return HistoryFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

**HistoryFragment.java (The problem is with this fragment)**

```
public class HistoryFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int HISTORY_LOADER_ID = 100;
    private static final String TAG = HistoryFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private HistoryListAdapter mAdapter;
    private SQLiteCursorLoader cursorLoader;
    Bundle save;
    View view;


    public static HistoryFragment newInstance(){
        return new HistoryFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        save=savedInstanceState;
        Log.d(TAG, new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(HISTORY_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        mAdapter = new HistoryListAdapter(getContext(),null,true);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            onDestroy();
            onCreate(save); //causing the issue in "case 2" mentioned above. If I remove it, data is showing but not updating until relaunch the app. I tried to put  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); here. but did not work
        }
    }

    private class HistoryListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


        private ActionMode mActionMode;

        public HistoryListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
            super(context, c, autoRequery);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, null);
            HistoryViewHolder historyViewHolder = new HistoryViewHolder();
            historyViewHolder.mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_history);
            historyViewHolder.mDateView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_history);
            historyViewHolder.mTimeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_history);
            view.setTag(historyViewHolder);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            final HistoryViewHolder historyViewHolder = (HistoryViewHolder) view.getTag();
            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID));
            String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_BARCODE_CONTENT));
            long dateTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATE));
            historyViewHolder.mContentView.setText(HistoryUtil.getDisplayableContent(content));
            historyViewHolder.mDateView.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(dateTime)));
            historyViewHolder.mTimeView.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(dateTime)));
            
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor c = HistoryDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getContext()).getHistoryById(id);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BarcodeDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.ID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.BARCODE_FORMAT, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_BARCODE_FORMAT)));
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.BARCODE_CONTENT, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_BARCODE_CONTENT)));
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.TIME_STAMP, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATE)));
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.RAW_IMAGE_DATA, Util.hexStringToByteArray(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RAW_IMAGE))));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static class HistoryViewHolder{
        TextView mContentView;
        TextView mDateView;
        TextView mTimeView;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Log.d(TAG,new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HistoryDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME;
        cursorLoader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getContext(),HistoryDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getContext()),sql,null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        Log.d(TAG,new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //onCreate(save) force this fragment to call onLoadFinished(). So I put mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); here
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        Log.d(TAG,new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG,new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

I tried so many things so far, but none of them seems to work. I want to know, what is the problem here and How can I solve this issue?